# Implementing OAuth Refresh Tokens that never expire

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, storage, jwt, access-token

In the context of OAuth 2, how does one deal with `refresh_token` expiry, or lack thereof?

I'm using JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) as `access_token`s with a short lifetime (expires after 20 minutes). From what I understand, this means I shouldn't have to store the `access_token`, only validate it (and consume the trusted information inside, like scopes).

However, I'm wondering how one implements `refresh_token`s. In my research, I've seen that Google and others have `refresh_token`s which are good forever, unless they are revoked, for any number of reasons. I assume this means the system must store all refresh tokens ever issued, so they can be marked as revoked.

Is this a problem when it comes to the storage of the tokens? It seems like you have a potentially infinite set of tokens which need to be stored and accessible forever.

Am I missing something? Are there best practices for implementing refresh tokens? Should they be (or NOT be) JWTs? Should the access_tokens also be stored, even when using JWTs? If so, is there any reason to keep them past their expiry time? What about JWT secrets changing over time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a good question, and refresh_tokens are in general wont expire, so that the application can generate new access token without asking the user to reauthenticate periodically,

But the application needs to enforce limitations for number of active refresh tokens allowed for a individual client, For eg:

Each OAuth client can have maximum of 20 active refresh_tokens only, if that limit reaches then the oldest token must be revoked and new one should be granted without rejecting the request.

And also if an refresh token is not consumed for a certain period say (6 months), then also the token needs to be revoked.

By this way, you can enforce limitation on refresh_token consumption, and here is the catch, this is how Google is also doing,

Refer [Google OAuth2 Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration)